# Get random docs from PouchDB (or CouchDB)

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm designing a quiz app with Angular and Ionic. I have about 2000 questions in json format and I choose PouchDB as database. CouchDB is perfect for me: I can add new question on a server and  app auto update question and answer.

But I have a doubt now: I cannot find a way to get random docs from Pouch. With my app I will generate quizzes from some selected section and I must get a variable number of docs from my DB.

I'm using the `db.allDocs([options], [callback])` api, I can set a limit but I cannot find a way to get random doc.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The first solution given by @nlawson isn't always working, for example I had to delete every document fetched so I lose the sequence of IDs, for example:

I had a list of documents with ids from 1 to 5

1- random is 3

2- get document with id 3

3- delete document with id 3
State of the database [1,2,4,5]

4- if random is anything but 3 repeat steps above, but if random is 3 or any id already deleted it cause problems, so this solution wasn't working, so I found another solution which is:

**ANSWER:**

Using the [Mango querie](https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html) find(), with this code

```
let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

db.find({
   selector: {_id: {$gte : '1'}},
   limit : 1,
   skip : rand-1,
});
```

First of all I get a random number, the max is the number of documents in my database and the min is 1 as the first id given to the first document.

After that I execute the find() query to select documents with an id great or equal to 1 (basically all), limit the query to retrieve only the first and start retrieving from rand-1.

To reuse our first example with rand equal 3 it will be something like that:

1- get all documents with an ID great or equal 1 
=> [1,2,3,4,5]

2- starting from rand-1 witch is 3-1=2 get the a limited number of documents the limit is 1
=> [2]

So it will always return the document on the position rand.

*P.S: to use find() you must install on top of pouch this library pouchdb.find.js*

Comment: I found that using skip/limit in the selector took about half a second to pick a random doc from the db. It didn't matter how many docs were in the db (i tried up to 1500). Too long if you're trying to get a few of them. My solution was to quickly get a list of all document ids (using mango find) and pick random ids from that. If docs were added or removed i'd get the list again. Note: my project is React Native with PouchDb+SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You could

1. Give your docs an `_id` of '1', '2', '3', etc., then use `Math.random()` to `get()` one randomly.
2. Or you could read in all the IDs using bulkDocs and then pick one randomly to `get()`, but that might be bad for performance if you have a lot of docs:

```
db.allDocs().then(function (res) {
  var ids = res.rows.map(function (row) { return row.id; });
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length);
  return db.get(ids[index]);
}).then(function (randomDoc) {
  // you got a randomDoc
}).catch(console.log.bind(console))
```

Comment: Thank you. Every docs has an id, but i need also a filter. For example I need 30 random docs with a particular value, so I cannot use this method because Id 1,3,6 belongs to a category and 2,4,5 to another. I think I must switch to SQLite

Comment: For that, you could use [queries](http://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html) along with the same logic. WebSQL is great, but keep in mind that then your Ionic app will only run on Android/iOS (i.e. not Windows Phone, Firefox OS, etc.).

Comment: For me as I get a random doc with the first method I need to delete this entry, therefor I lose the sequence of ids so I cannot use the first method